# Decomposing matrix as tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, tensor-decomposition

I have a matrix $F\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n^2}$ for some integer $n>1$. I know in some cases, I can decompose $F$ as
$$F = \mathbf{v}^\dagger\otimes \mathcal{F}$$
where $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{F}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. In general, though, it's not possible to do this, and I have some counterexamples showing this is not possible. However, **is it possible to decompose $F$ as**:
$$F = \sum_{j = 1}^r \mathbf{v}_r^\dagger \otimes \mathcal{F}_r$$
Or is this also not possible? Is there a relevant theorem or property I need to know? If this decomposition is possible, is it possible to bound $r$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: Hint: take $r=n$ and let each $\mathbf{v}_j$ be a canonical basis vector in $\mathbb R^n\,.$ The $n\times n$-matrices ${\cal F}_j$ are a partition of $F\,.$ It would be an exaggeration to call this a theorem. Take a low-dimenional example and write things out using the definition of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).